# Wordpress API with Tabs

Tags: php, wordpress

### I'm learning how to make a Wordpress Setting API with Tabs for admin section but every time refresh the page I get this error message saying [Screenshot of the problem](https://gyazo.com/1ddcb5a5c4e708e5844301fd49f18d63)

```
<div class="wrap">
        <h2>Theme Options - <?php echo get_current_theme();?></h2>
    </div>

    <?php settings_errors(); ?>
    <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
    <?php if( isset( $_GET[ 'tab' ] ) ) { $active_tab = $_GET[ 'tab' ]; } 
        $active_tab = isset( $_GET[ 'tab' ] ) ? $_GET[ 'tab' ] : 'homepage_options'; ?>
      <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
        <?php if( isset( $_GET[ 'tab' ] ) ) { $active_tab = $_GET[ 'tab' ]; } 
        $active_tab = isset( $_GET[ 'tab' ] ) ? $_GET[ 'tab' ] : 'homepage_options'; ?>
        <a style="margin-left: 0px !important;"href="?page=kdrusha-options" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'homepage_options' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">Social Options</a>
        <a href="?page=kdrusha-options&tab=news_options" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'news_options' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">Front-Page News Options</a>
        <a href="?page=kdrusha-options&tab=youtube_options" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'youtube_options' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">YouTube Videos Options</a>
        <a href="?page=kdrusha-options&tab=event_options" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'event_options' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">Event Options</a>
    </h2>

    <form method="post" action="options.php">

        <?php
         if($active_tab == 'homepage_options') {
                settings_fields('kdrusha-homepage-group');
                do_settings_sections('kdrusha-homepage-options');
                submit_button();
            }

        ?>

    </form>
```

Comment: Set up a virtual host and see if it works then.

Comment: I'm already using MAMP as virtual host @TheFallen

Comment: I think you're accessing your server directly, because the URL says `localhost`. Do you have a virtual host setup in Apache and in `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: No, don't have virtual host setup do know where I can get Apache virtual host. @TheFallen

Comment: This should help you out - http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/vhosts_mamp.php

Comment: After that make sure you have `.htaccess` file for Wordpress, so you can rewrite the URL - https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Comment: Thank you! for help me @TheFallen